# findOneAndUpdate don't update field name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

field name does not change. why ?
....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

[image]

```
router.post('/bio/firstname', (req, res) => {

  Habalka.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: "d9aa8566-75fe-4108-a72e-1b67e79cf40c"},
    {name: 5}
  )
    .then((data) => {
      res.json({error: false, data: data})
    });

});
```

model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const HabalkaSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String
  },
  bio: {
    firstname: {},
    lastname: {},
    middlename: {},
    company: {}
  },
  rating: [

  ],
  files: [
    {
      _id: {
        type: String
      },
      destination: {
        type: String
      },
      filename: {
        type: String
      },
      path: {
        type: String
      },
      folder: {
        type: String
      },
      info: {
        size: {
          type: Number
        },
        mimetype: {
          type: String
        },
        encoding: {
          type: String
        },
        originalname: {
          type: String
        },
        fieldname: {
          type: String
        },
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      },
      bio: {
        type: Object
      },
      userId: String,
      guessId: {},
    }
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
module.exports = Habalka = mongoose.model('habalka', HabalkaSchema);
```

Comment: Do not add dot spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working. It could also be helpful to look up how to create a [MCVE] - consider trimming out code that's not directly related to the problem.

Comment: and what should I write? from the title it’s already clear what I need, I don’t know what to write

Comment: Anything other than spammy text would be preferable - you can elaborate to explain more of the problem, and what sort of debugging you've tried, and so on.

Comment: of course I can write something else, but this will only complicate the issue by writing more unnecessary information

Comment: Please describe the expected behaviour. You just show your sample data and your code. You should also include the current behaviour and what you expect. Also, you haven't defined a `name` filed in the schema but you want to update it. It will be removed during validation.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming the route works fine you just have a syntax error in your update, try this:

```
  Habalka.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: "d9aa8566-75fe-4108-a72e-1b67e79cf40c"},
    {$set: {name: 5}}
  )
    .then((data) => {
      res.json({error: false, data: data})
    });
```

Comment: yes route works fine, but it still don't work http://joxi.ru/E2pdvMGh76XMv2

Comment: my guess you set the mongoose schema name field to be `string` so mongoose is "protecting" you from mistakes, the syntax i provided is correct